# 301 Redirect causing too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a primary domain on my hosting account to an add-on domain within the same server. Let's say:

domain1.com

to

domain2.com

I created an .htaccess file within the public html folder and added this code:

Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com

If I go to the new site (the one I want directed to), I get this error:

www.domain.com redirected you too many times.

What can I do to redirect domain1 to domain2?

[image]

Comment: Do the domains share the same root folder / files?

Comment: @Garytje Doman1 is the primary domain and is in the root. Domain2 is an add on domain which has a folder called domain2 with all of its files within it.

Comment: Does domain 2 has a .htaccess file as well? this sounds like something strange, i could post a possible solution, but am not sure if it is going to work for your situation

Comment: Yes, the domain2 has an `.htaccess` file. It is just for a clean url, though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the structure of the folders, this can be achieved by using rewriteConditions: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond

Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way the `RewriteRule` only applies to when the `HTTP_HOST` contains domain1.com

`RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f` means that it should not apply to files.

Comment: So, where you put `^domain1` do I put the actual domain1 url in?

Comment: Correct, using a Rewritecondition tells the following rewriterule only to activate when the condition is met. So if the current host is domain1, redirect to domain2

Comment: Just tried doing it like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www.domain1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]` and it doesn't do anything. However, it doesn't create an error on the domain2 page.

Comment: leave out the https:// and possibly the www. part and you should be good, https:// is not a part of http_host

Comment: It doesn't redirect and it removes images on domain2 that I am getting from domain1

Comment: off course it removes images, you wanted to redirect a complete domain, if you want to keep files intact you need to add an extra condition `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: So, I would have to write each filename or can I do a folder?

Comment: i started a chat to further assist your specific problem, when we are done, i will update the final answer.

Comment: Thanks! I added an image to help with understanding file placement.